# How can I let people install my package by apt-get?

Tags: debian, fedora, apt, yum, debian-installer

I have a set of binary packages that I want the user to be able to install from command line via `apt-get` or `yum` without having to host it myself on a server. I have heard of `reprepro` and pushing it to the Debian project itself. What are some of the ways I can achieve it? I am at an intermediate level when it comes to linux. A step by step approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides of the official repositories of the distributions, an user can add a repository for software outside of the regular packages of the distribution. Instead of installing a .deb (debian/Ubuntu), the user simply add a Personal Package Archive (*PPA*), and he could install, remove, update the packages using apt-get.

For Debian/Ubuntu you can open an account on **launchpad** and using a Personal Package Archive (*PPA*), distribute software and updates in the same way as the original repositories. Create your source package, upload it and Launchpad will build binaries and then host them in your own apt repository.

For Fedora/RedHat there is https://repos.fedorapeople.org/ that is barely the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a Packages file for the current directory fairly easily:

```
dpkg-scanpackages . | tee Packages | gzip -9 > Packages.gz
```

That will generate relative paths to the package files (which can be in subdirectories). All you have to do is point people at the top level directory with something like this in their `sources.list`:

```
deb https://host/directory ./
```

Other than that, there are hosted options. Launchpad certainly one for free stuff but there are companies like [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) who will take commercial packages for a number of different formats.